# CryptoJS : key.clamp is not a function

Tags: javascript, jwt, cryptojs

```
TypeError: key.clamp is not a function
  at Object.init (path/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac.js:58:18)
```

The error above occurs when I try to create JWT in Javascript with the relevant code below.

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token.join("."), secret);
```

crypto-js/hmac.js:58:18 has `key.clamp();` and I'm not sure what would be the best approach. I tried with `HmacSHA512` but it returns the same error.

I'm running with `npm 6.1.0` `node v6.10.3` `crypto-js ^3.1.9-1`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce, with `token = ["a","b"]` and `secret = "mySecret";`. What is the `typeof` of your `secret`?

Comment: Thanks Adelin, `typeof` `secret` is object.

Comment: I'm not sure that's how they intended it to be. In all [their samples](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js), they are using a `string`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [their samples](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js), `secret` (or `key` as they call it), should be a `string`.

As such, using `CryptoJS` like this should work just fine:

```
const token = "a,b"; // fake token
const secret = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("mySecret"); //encode mySecret into UTF-8 as suggested in the comments
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token.split(","), secret);
console.log(hash);
```

Comment: I'm geting `There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  TypeError: r.clamp is not a function` do you know why? Just copied your example

Comment: This code is working for me. If it is not working for you, it is either because you are using a buggy version of crypto (try to update), or because you have an error in the code (try posting another question if that's the case)

Comment: I have read somewhere that the problem was because I first need to encode mySecret into UTF-8. Then it worked

Comment: `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(plainTextPassword));` but I'm using it for base64 encoding. Maybe I messed up your code haha